# JQuery alerting when a select box is changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ok so all of the other functions I've done this same way have worked so far. This one for whatever reason will not work.I don't know if there is something I"m missing or if maybe a potential error in the code earlier could cause this. Here is my code:

```
  jQuery("#teamTab_addPlayerForm").on('change', 'select#teamTab_suggestedPlayer', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('It Worked');

});
```

And here is the PHP file that calls it:

```
 $output .= '<div id="ld_addPlayerFunction" style="clear:both; width:100%;"><h3>Add Player</h3>';
        $standins = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'kdc_user_sync ORDER BY computedMMR ASC');
        $output .= '<form id="teamTab_addPlayerForm" action="" method="POST">
            <select id="teamTab_suggestedPlayer" name="suggestedPlayer">
                <option value="base">Suggested Player</option>';
            foreach($standins as $standin){
                $playerID = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueDesigner_players WHERE userID = ' . $standin->userID);
                $test = true;
                if($playerID != ''){
                    $leagueTest = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueDesigner_league_players WHERE playerID = ' . $playerID);
                    foreach($leagueTest as $test){
                        if ($test->leagueID == $leagueID){
                            $test = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($standin->computedMMR < ($suggestedMMR + 100) && $standin->computedMMR > ($suggestedMMR -100) && $test == true){
                    $output .= '<option value="' . $standin->userID . '">' . substr($standin->profileName, 0, 20) . ' - ' . $standin->computedMMR . ' MMR</option>';
                }
            } 

        $output .= '</select><br />';
        $output .= '</form>';
```

The output is then echoed later in the script. So one user has told me to use document instead of #teamTab_addPlayerForm and it works, but I'm wondering why this previous code worked fine and that one didn't:

```
jQuery("#teamTab_teamListForm").on('change', 'select#teamTab_teamSelect', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).attr('disabled', true);
    var teamID = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery('select#teamTab_leagueSelect').attr('disabled', true);
    var leagueID = jQuery('select#teamTab_leagueSelect').val();
    data = { action: "leagueDesignerTeamsTabLoadTeamPlayers", leagueID: leagueID, teamID: teamID };
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST', url: ajaxurl, data: data, dataType: 'html', success: function(response) {
                if (response == "error") {
                    jQuery('select#teamTab_teamSelect').attr('disabled', false);
                    alert('There was an error processing your request');
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('select#teamTab_teamSelect').attr('disabled', false);
                    jQuery('select#teamTab_leagueSelect').attr('disabled', false);
                    jQuery('.ld_teamEdit').remove();
                    jQuery('#ld_addPlayerFunction').remove();
                    jQuery('div#ld_teamTabTeamInfo').remove();
                    jQuery('#teamTab_teamListForm').after(response);
                }
                }});
});
```

That was the code that is dealing with select boxes in the same way. And here is the PHP code:

```
function leagueDesignerTeamsTabLoadLeagueTeams () { 
global $wpdb;
$leagueID = $_POST['leagueID']; //Pull the POST'd leagueID
$output = '<select id="teamTab_teamSelect" name="team"><option value="">Choose a Team</option>'; //Output...
$errors = 0; //Error checking...
$teams = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueDesigner_teams WHERE leagueID = ' . $leagueID);
foreach($teams as $team){
    $output .= '<option value="' . $team->teamID . '"';
    if ($_POST['team'] == $team->teamID){
        $output .= ' selected';
    }
    $output .= '>' . $team->teamID . '. ' . $team->teamName . '</option>';
}
if (!$teams) {
    $errors++;
}
$output .= '</select>';
if ($errors == 0) { echo $output; } else { echo 'error'; }
die(); // this is required to return a proper result
```

}

Comment: You are binding `change` event to a non existing element `#teamTab_addPlayerForm`, which is later included in the DOM. So you should bind to more prior parent element which is already in the DOM or just do `$(document).on...` instead.

Comment: any errors thrown in browr console? Does element exist when you run code?

Comment: @Rahil Wazir Well that worked but the jQuery statement directly above the one I just showed you calls something very similar I'm editing my question to show the previous code.

Comment: @charlietfl There are no errors in the browser console and the elements fire up as expected in the DOM when I inspect it with firebug.

Comment: @Nash Probably the latter script worked because the the element `#teamTab_teamListForm` already exist to the DOM.

Comment: @Rahil Wazir No the latter script is actually added using ajax after the first select box is selected the latter script comes up, after that is selected the first script comes up. Oh well I guess as long as it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The element is created after page load so you need to bind it to an already existing element (see below)

```
$(document).on('change', '.class-name', function () {
    //Commands to run on change
});
```